# git does not find all submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

i have the problem where i am trying to clone a repository with quite a number nested submodules. The problem is, that when i use `git clone --recurse-submodule` it does not clone all the nested submodules. 
I don't think it's something to do with `--depth` either, because there is a submodule missing even on the same "depth" as others, but the others **are** cloned. 
Running neither `git submodule update --init --recursive` nor `git submodule update --remote --recursive` helps in this case. 
I also checked the .gitmodule files in the repository and they do include all the submodules.
There are no errors or anything to speak of, as the clone is being made, it's just missing submodules. 
Is the some kind of maximum number of submodules that i have to adjust? 
I would appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it a public repo, can we clone it? "*Is the some kind of maximum number of submodules*" No. There must be some errors — disabled protocol (`git://` no longer work on most hosts), wrong host (no longer in DNS), connection error, timeout, memory error (not enough RAM or disk space).

Comment: unfortunately it is not. and i just cloned it again to check for any errors and there are none. it just does not clone all the submodules there are :/
Maybe let me know what would help you understand my situation better and i'll see what i can share